# Why AccessController is not blocking the non-privileged access

Tags: java, sandbox, whitelist, securitymanager, scriptengine

Disclaimer: The old version of the question was confusing `SecurityManager` and `AccessController`. But now I know I've made a mistake and the question is refined.

The stem is pretty straight forward; I'm looking for a way to limit what a script can do in some ScriptEngine.

I've read some similar questions, old and new. There seems to be a solution for `NashornScriptEngine` using a class called `ClassFilter`. But I'm looking for a generic way regardless of their scripting engine implementation. Some suggest that Java's `AccessController` is the way. So I've started to read and play with `AccessController`, so far I've got this:

```
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("nashorn");

Permissions perms = new Permissions();
ProtectionDomain domain = new ProtectionDomain(new CodeSource( null, (Certificate[]) null ), perms);
AccessControlContext acc = new AccessControlContext(new ProtectionDomain[] { domain });

AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction() {
    @Override
    public Object run() {
        try {
            //I want the following line to throw a SecurityException
            return engine.eval("var System = Java.type('java.lang.System'); print(System.getProperty('java.home'));");
        }
        catch (ScriptException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }},
    acc
);

//At the same time I want the following line to work
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.home"));
```

And the script runs as if there's no AccessController involved!

So my question is; is `AccessController` the way to do this? And if it is, then how should I do it?

Comment: definitely the way to do it, but I don't see a SecurityManager being registered in your code

Comment: Could you please show me how to fix this code? I don't know what's wrong with it. And one more thing, the rest of my application is good as it is. In other words, all I want to apply the SecurityManager to is the `engine.eval` line not the rest of application. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to fix the problem here myself. After reading a little more, I found out that the `AccessController` has no effect if the `SecurityManager` is not activated. And here's how you activate it:

1. Add two VM options: `-Djava.security.manager
   -Djava.security.policy=security.policy`
2. Create a `security.policy` file in the project's root folder, with the following content:
   `grant {
       permission java.security.AllPermission;
   };`

This will activate the `SecurityManager` for your project and grant it all the permissions. In other words, it will just activate `SecurityManager` but your code will work as before. Now you can control parts of application's access control using the code given above.